# Is there a list of countries and organizations blocking Tor?

Tags: bridge, censorship

Is there a list of countries and organizations blocking Tor somewhere?

So I am basically looking for a list where the use of Bridge Nodes is the only way to connect to the Tor network.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/china),  **China** has succeeded to block Tor partially *because China’s Internet is fundamentally different.*

Apparently, **Iran** went a little bit farther in blocking Tor according to this [documentation](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/iran-blocks-tor-tor-releases-same-day-fix).

Tor is used to circumvent censorship:

[image]

Russia also wants to do the same ([VPN and TOR Ban Looming on the Horizon for Russia](https://torrentfreak.com/vpn-and-tor-ban-looming-on-the-horizon-for-russia-150212/)) but apparently it can not.

Also, after the recent attacks on Paris, **France** want to ban the use of Tor ([France wants to BAN Tor and Free Wi-Fi Services after Paris Terror Attacks](http://thehackernews.com/2015/12/France-tor-ban.html)) but for the moment I can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no. Because even the countries that officially are not blockin Tor are often trying to play bad things with it, like Russia I'm currently living in...